# How to call API for every 5 mins when using HttpResponse in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am using a `HttpResponse` Object to return the response. Now I am trying to implement a timer to hit the API for every 5 mins but using `HttpResponse` Object in the service I am unable to subscribe to the timer to hit the API. How do I achieve this?

Service:

```
async getTest(pagenumber: number, pagesize: number): Promise<HttpResponse<Object>> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    observe: 'response' as 'response'
  }
  const response = await this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.Service.getTestURL + '/' + pagenumber + '? pageSize=' + pagesize, { observe: 'response' }).toPromise();
    return response;
  }
```

ts:

```
this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.myservice.checkdata())
).subscribe(result => this.statustext = result);
```

I've tried all the solutions so don't mark as duplicate question.

Comment: What's wrong with Angular's http service? :)

Comment: @vino : why do you want to call your api every 5 minutes ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to show notifications if anyone add new form so i want to hit the API automatically.

Comment: HttpClient is the latest one @ Jeremy Thille

Comment: If you try `this.myService.checkData().subscribe((result) => this.statustext = result)` does it work the way you expect ? I mean, without the `timer` from rxjs library.

Comment: I just tried the above typescript code but i can't able to subscribe because the response returns HttpResponse Object

Comment: @Florian Without timer also its not working. I used normally like let response = <HttpResponse<Object>>await this.regulationService.getTest(1, 1); to hit the service but i dont know how to achieve timer function in this way

Comment: @vino : Ok, so your problem is with your service method `getTest`. is there any particular reason why you're using `async` ?

Comment: Yes async method is used to show spinner until response came server

Comment: @vino you don't need `async` for that. Angular `HttpClient` methods return an observable, you can subscribe on it and you can manage your spinner. Can you create a small stackblitz with your error ?

Comment: I understand but now i cant able to remove async from service. Is there any other way to achieve timer with my above code

Answer (score 0):

use can use setInterval like this

```
export class AppComponent  {
  intervalID:any
ngOnInit(){
 this.intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){console.log('api Call goes here')}, 300000);
}

ngOnDestroy(){
      clearInterval(this.intervalID);

}
}
```

In setInterval, you can put the api call

i hope this helps

Comment: But in your example you are not using setInterval right?How to use setInterval to call API

Comment: You mean Observable.Interval? If i use like this i got error Property interval does not exist on typeof Observable

Comment: @vino i've update the answer there was some issue with stackbliz so my code was not updated please check the demo code i've put here it is working fine

Comment: If you run this code then it will print in the console every 5 min(3000000 ms)

Comment: Update answer also not working.can you share the stackblitz again?